Thuja orientalis after 2 days of heatwave 38-40ºC
I bought a small thuja orientalis a month ago (around 50 cm tall) and put it on a balcony where it receives direct sun from 3pm to around 7 pm, the rest of the day it's on the shade, I water it 1 time every 5-6 days putting 3-4 cm of water on a dish and letting it soak from below.
The plant went through a heatwave the last few days and now the leaves are hard and dropping, I was wondering if I can do something to make it recover.


